# Unable to identify object using descriptive programming but able to do so with description object

Tags: angularjs, qtp, hp-uft

On my application i have to search for an alphanumeric id which return one or more rows of data. On each of these rows a link is present i have to click on the first link.

Unfortunately it doesn't have any unique properties so i cannot add it to the OR. Instead i used descriptive programming something like below

```
'returns false
page.Link("class:=ng-binding","innertext:=AplhaID","html tag:=A").Exist
```

QTP fails to identify the object with the above code. So Instead of this i tried using Description object something like the below code

```
Set oDesc = Description.Object
oDesc("class").Value = "ng-binding"
oDesc("html tag").Value = "A"
oDesc("innertext").Value = "AplhaID"

Set lnk = page.ChildObjects(oDesc)

'gives me 2 which is correct. There are two links
msgbox lnk.Count

'highlights the correct link
lnk(0).Highlight
```

I do not know what could be causing this behavior. I thought is could be because multiple links match the description but I perform this search for multiple ids and eventhough multiple rows are returned the descriptive programming code is able to identify the correct row and proceed.

I looked at [QTP descriptive programming issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589270/qtp-descriptive-programming-issue) but my link's property values do not have special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Descriptive string method, ensure that you have only one object matching the given properties.

Below statement might fail if there are more than 1 object with the given properties.

```
page.Link("class:=ng-binding","innertext:=AplhaID","html tag:=A").Exist
```

So , you need to make the statement to find an object uniquely. Try this. It will work!

```
page.Link("class:=ng-binding","innertext:=AplhaID","html tag:=A", "index:=0").Exist
```

Comment: you are correct. I reviewed the search using the other IDs and it was only with this ID that i was getting multiple rows. Thanks!